# htaccess remove php extension except for one specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP project, and I need to hide the .php extension in the URL with `.htaccess`.
I can already do that with this `.htaccess` file

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

now, I need to allow the .php extention in the index.php inside the folder called php which is inside a folder called server (myproject/server/php/index.php).

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For more details, please the following the link.

https://www.plothost.com/kb/how-to-remove-php-html-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: it's local emviroment

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Please try the again by copying it.